# Compare today's value with yesterday's value and return data if difference is > 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Products` table where prices of products are updated every day.

| eff_date | product_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-25 | P1 | 150 |
| 2022-11-25 | P2 | 75.8 |
| 2022-11-25 | P3 | 2.9 |
| 2022-11-26 | P1 | 180.5 |
| 2022-11-26 | P2 | 77 |
| 2022-11-26 | P4 | 13.92 |

But sometimes not all products will have data for each date (like how p3 do not have data for 26th and p4 do not have data for 25th).

Consider today's date is 26th then I want to compare today's price with yesterday's price and if difference is > 10% (price increased by 10% or more )then I want output like below:

| eff_date | product_id | todays_price | yesterdays_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-26 | P1 | 180.5 | 150 |

Comment: Use `LAG` and a Common Table Expression (CTE) or derived table.

Comment: eff_date field is type datetime? @Sachin

Comment: @Andriu1510 no its date only. Also i updated the requirement.actually i want output only if difference is 10% and 10 units

Comment: It's still not clear. Assume there is no data for yesterday because yesterday was Sunday. Should then the price be compared to Saturday (26th november) or should Mondays be skipped?

Comment: @JonasMetzler everyday we will have data (even on weekends). Just that not all products will have data everyday

Comment: I have come up with below query but not sure how to fetch only those records whose value is increased by 10%                                                                     select a.eff_date,b.eff_date,  a.product_id, a.price as todays_price, b.price as yesterdays_price
from (select * from products pm where eff_date=cast(CURRENT_DATE as date)) a 
inner join 
(select * from products pm where eff_date=cast(CURRENT_DATE -1 as date)) b
on a.product_id=b.product_id

Comment: Please update the initial question with above. Always when providing additional information and/or answering questions then update the question - do not provide additional information or answer as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your date to the current_date,
you can do like Lamun said.

A CTE gets  you all the data you need

```
CREATE TABLE products
    ("eff_date" date, "product_id" varchar(2), "price" numeric)
;
    
INSERT INTO products
    ("eff_date", "product_id", "price")
VALUES
    ('2022-11-27', 'P1', 150),
    ('2022-11-27', 'P2', 75.8),
    ('2022-11-27', 'P3', 2.9),
    ('2022-11-28', 'P1', 180.5),
    ('2022-11-28', 'P2', 77),
    ('2022-11-28', 'P4', 13.92),
  ('2022-11-28', 'P5', 150),
  ('2022-11-27', 'P5', 180.5)
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 8
> ```

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT
    "eff_date", "product_id", "price"
    ,LAG("price") OVER(PARTITION BY "product_id" ORDER BY "eff_date") last_price
, extract(day from "eff_date"::timestamp - LAG("eff_date") OVER(PARTITION BY "product_id" ORDER BY "eff_date")::timestamp ) diffdays
FROM 
  products)
SELECT "eff_date", "product_id" , "price" as "today's price" , last_price as "yesterday's price"
   FROm CTE
WHERE diffdays = 1 AND "eff_date" = current_date AND  ABS( ( 1 - "price"/ last_price)) > 0.1
```

| eff_date | product_id | today's price | yesterday's price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-28 | P1 | 180.5 | 150 |
| 2022-11-28 | P5 | 150 | 180.5 |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OejDd5KH)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` which groups your data based on product_id and sorts by the date, then check if the current price >= previous price *1.1 to cover your condition the price must have increased by at least 10%.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    eff_date, 
    product_id,
    price,
    LAG(eff_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
        ORDER BY eff_date
    ) previous_date,
    LAG(price,1) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
        ORDER BY eff_date
    ) previous_price
FROM products)
SELECT eff_date, product_id, 
price AS todays_price, 
previous_price AS yesterdays_price
FROM cte
WHERE 
eff_date = previous_date + 1 AND 
price >= previous_price * 1.1;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ba9j7Hl-)

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the below query. Can someone please confirm if it's correct?

```
select a.eff_date as todays_date,b.eff_date as yesterdays_date, a.product_id, a.price as todays_price, b.price as yesterdays_price,
(((a.price - b.price) / b.price) * 100) as perc_change

from (select * from products where eff_date=cast(CURRENT_DATE as date)) a 

inner join 

(select * from products where eff_date=cast(CURRENT_DATE -1 as date)) b

on a.product_id=b.product_id 

where (((a.price - b.price) / b.price) * 100) > 10
```

Comment: No, it's not correct because of different reasons. One of them is you are checking the current date, but this date means nothing if your table contains other dates. Furthermore, selecting twice from the same table with JOIN can cause very poor performance, this should be avoided. Please check the other answers. You can verify using the linked fiddle samples that they work as you described.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I want to always compare today's price with yesterday's price that's why i used CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE -1. Data of other dates are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create temporary table temp1 as
    select 
    eff_date,
    product_id,
    price as todays_price
    lag(price) over(partition by product_id order by eff_date) as yesterdays_price,
    from products
    
    select * from temp1
    where 
    (todays_price-yesterdays_price)/yesterdays_price >= 0.10
```

Note that we are only including only those products whose price increased 10%